# Multiple event listeners being added to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, constructor, addeventlistener

I am creating and appending elements via class object constructor with a button press, and need each individual element created to have an event listener that will call a method from a class to return the values of the object tied to the element.

Everything seems to work fine when I have a single element that was created. When I have two or more elements, it will output n results where n = the amount of elements that were created. 4 elements created = 4x the outputs, which ruins anything that I want to do with the data output.

For example, if I have one element that has the properties of square and red, then clicking it correctly outputs square and red. But if I add an element with the object properties of circle and green, then clicking on EITHER element will output both 'square red' and 'circle green'

```js
// Utility function
function onEvent(event, selector, callback) {
    return selector.addEventListener(event, callback);
}

onEvent('click', submit, function() {
    let shape = new Shape(shapeInput.value, colorInput.value);
    shape.createShape();
    output.innerHTML = `${shape.shapeColor} ${shape.shapeName} `

    shapeContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        let target = e.target;

        if (target.matches('div')) {
            output.innerHTML = `${shape.getInfo()}`;
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried looking for ways to check if the element already has an event listener and to ignore it, but didn't have any luck. I have also tried to add a `removeEventListener` section, to no success. Is there something I'm missing here or am I completely wrong with my approach?

Comment: How you are creating the objects? I think you need to modify this line let shape = new Shape(shapeInput.value, colorInput.value);

Comment: Hi @Mehrwarz, that is the call to my class constructor, which just has properties for name, color, and the getInfo method to return both name + color. Inside my class I have a simple createShape() method that appends div elements onto the HTML. How would you suggest it be changed?

Comment: I think your event listeners is working based on class and the circle and square has same class. use properties instead of class to select the element and add event listener, can post the code how you add the listener?

Comment: Please share reproducible code.

Comment: @Mehrwarz Hi, you're correct! I'm selecting a class for '.shape' in my document which is assigned to shapeContainer in the js. Sorry if my code is very verbose/abstract, I'm very new to programming. I get the same bug regardless if the shape is a square or a circle, I think the issue is something to do with an event listener being added to every existing element every time a button is clicked, but I don't know how to fix that. When I inspect the event listeners of the elements in my webpage it shows extra listeners on each element.

Comment: if you post the code you are adding the listener I can find the way to come over the issue. you may use document.querySelectoreAll([propertiesName]).addEventListener()

Comment: @KairavThakar Sorry, I realized a fiddle would be best. https://jsfiddle.net/ypu15qgf/ input only lowercase square/circle and any default css color.

Comment: Thanks for the example, Will check it.

Comment: jsfiddle code is not working

Comment: It's working for me, sorry... not sure what to do. Thanks for taking a look at it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I did not respond let.
this will work for you.

```
   'use strict';

    // Selectors 
    const shapeContainer = select('.shape-container');
    const submit = select('.submit');
    const shapeInput = select('.shape-input');
    const colorInput = select('.color-input');
    const shapeSelector = select('.shape');
    const output = select('span');


    class Shape {
        constructor(name, color) {
            this._name = name;
            this._color = color;
        }

        set shapeName(name) {
            if (name instanceof Shape && this._name.length > 0) {
                this._name = name;
            } else {
                throw new TypeError('Shape name is invalid');
            }
        }

        get shapeName() {
            return this._name;
        }

        set shapeColor(color) {
            if (color instanceof Shape && this._color.length > 0) {
                this._color = color;
            } else {
                throw new TypeError('Color is invalid');
            }
        }

        get shapeColor() {
            return this._color;
        }

        createShape() {

            let element = {
                tag : document.createElement('div'),
                color : this._color,
                name : this._name,
            }

            document.querySelector('.shape-container').appendChild(element.tag);
            element.tag.style.cssText += 'background-color:' + element.color;

            // Shape definition
            if (this._name == 'circle') {
                element.tag.classList.add('circle', 'shape');
            } else if (this._name == 'square') {
                element.tag.classList.add('square', 'shape');
            } else {
                throw new TypeError('shapeName is invalid');
            }
            element.tag.addEventListener('click', function () {
                console.log(element.color," ",element.name)
                if (element.tag.matches('div')) {
                    output.innerHTML = getInfo(element);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    // Utility functions 
    
    function select(selector, parent = document) {
        return parent.querySelector(selector);
    }

     function onEvent(event, selector, callback) {
        return selector.addEventListener(event, callback);
    }

    function getInfo (e) {
        console.log(e.color,e.name)
        return `${e.name} ${e.color}`;
    }

    let arr = [];

    onEvent('click', submit, function () {
        let shape = new Shape(shapeInput.value, colorInput.value);
        arr.push(shape);
        console.log(arr);
        shape.createShape();
    });
```

Comment: the event should be created while the shape is created not in a separate function later on. Second the event listener was triggered on the container click, I change it to on ship click this way each shape will behave differently. also when you were creating the shape your code was updating the class properties of name and color not adding properties to shape you where creating only the element as HTML tag. I create the element as an object with properties of Tag, Name and color and used them on the click event listener for each shape. My English is not good i hope i could explain.